# applying numpy.searchsorted over multiple axes

Tags: python, search, optimization, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to pass a 2d array of sorted values and a 1d array of values to `searchsorted` and have it return a corresponding 1d array of index values. I have to perform this operation many times, and I'm trying to find an efficient way to do so. Ultimately, I'd like to pass a 3d array of values sorted along an axis, a 2d array of values to search for and have the function return a 2d array of indices.

Here is a `MLE`

```
from numpy import *
random.seed(1234)

a = zeros((4,10))
a[:,1:-1] = random.rand(4,8)
a[:,1:-1].sort(1)
a[:,-1] = 1.

v = random.rand(4)

res = array([searchsorted(a[j], v[j]) for j in xrange(4)])
```

where `res` should be [9, 1, 7, 6]

Is there an efficient way to do this? Ideally, I'd like to avoid Cython if at all possible. If it helps, each array being searched over should have 9-10 elements, while the number of values being searched for is larger (100-1000 elements) so the 2d array being passed would have a size of 1000x10.

Comment: [Here's an issue about it.](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4224)

Comment: You already found a way. Is it really that inefficient? Maybe you could try `numpy.vectorize`?

Comment: Don't bring attention to edits like the one you made. It makes your post look unprofessional, and the edit history is much better at it than you are.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace

```
res = array([searchsorted(a[j], v[j]) for j in xrange(4)])
```

with:

```
res = (a.T < v).sum(axis=0)
```

That's it (I'll write the proof of correctness in the comment). In the above line, although we do not binary search, since we vectorize the iteration on the larger dimension, we get a **40x speedup (on my Mac).** This speed up is gained with the 2d array size of `(1000,10)`.

In order to measure the execution, you can use the following command to average the runtime (`1.67` milli seconds) of your original command in 100 executions:

```
python2 -m timeit -n 100 \
    -s 'import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1234); a = np.zeros((1000,10)); a[:,1:-1] = np.random.rand(1000,8); a[:,1:-1].sort(1); a[:,-1] = 1.; v = np.random.rand(1000)' \
    'res = np.array([np.searchsorted(a[j], v[j]) for j in xrange(1000)])'

100 loops, best of 3: 1.67 msec per loop
```

while the proposed execution takes only `41.7` micro seconds:

```
python2 -m timeit -n 100 \
    -s 'import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1234); a = np.zeros((1000,10)); a[:,1:-1] = np.random.rand(1000,8); a[:,1:-1].sort(1); a[:,-1] = 1.; v = np.random.rand(1000)' \
    'res = (a.T < v).sum(axis=0)'

100 loops, best of 3: 41.7 usec per loop
```

Comment: Reason of correctness: given the 2d matrix `A` of size `m x n` and the 1d vector `v` of size `m`, `C = A.T < v` is a 2D matrix of boolean values in which `C[i,j] == A[i,j] < v[i]`. By taking the sum of `C.sum(axis=0)`, we are counting the number of indices in each row `i` of `A` that are smaller than `v[i]`. Given the fact that rows of `A` are sorted, the number of elements smaller than `v[i]` is the same value as `searchsorted(a[i], v[i])`.